# Touch a blob and change its ETag without downloading content and uploading in Windows Azure

Tags: c#, azure

This question is mainly asked because I am not 100% sure how ETags are calculated.

I am using the .net c# library, latest version, and is wondering how I can touch a blob updating the Etag without downloading the file and uploading it again.

I assume I could just change the ETag with SetPropertiesAsync() but I do not know what I should put in the ETag Property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change ETag property of a blob programmatically. It's a system-defined property which gets updated everytime blob is updated. One way to change ETag value of a blob without reuploading it is to change either one of its properties (like cache-control etc.) or change metadata of the blob. I just tried this by changing the blob's metadata and when I fetched the properties for that blob, I got a new ETag value.

Comment: Thanks for testing it for me :) My Solution was then:         public Task Touch(string storePath)
        {
            var blob = GetBlobReference(storePath);
            blob.Properties.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
            return blob.SetPropertiesAsync();
        }

Comment: Woops, that was also system defined :D

Comment: That's what I was about to write :)

Comment: Is the LastModified also changed when setting properties then ? or only when content is changed?

Comment: Yes. The last modified date also changes when you update properties and/or metadata.