# Update LastModified on an Azure Blob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm porting code to work with Azure's Storage SDK in C#.

Traditionally, I'd call this to update modified the last write/modified time of a file:

```
File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(fileName, lastWriteTimeUtc);
```

To update a blob's last modified time, I'm trying to do something like this but can't because LastModified is not accessible:

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
blob.Properties.LastModified = lastWriteTimeUtc;
blob.SetProperties();
```

Compiler error:

> Property or indexer 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobProperties.LastModified' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

How can I update the LastModified property? It won't always be updated to the current time, so I can't just reupload/touch the file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you want is effectively a "touch" operation. You must re-upload the BLOB to change the `LastModified` property.

**EDIT**

If you want to manage your own custom last modified variable, the best thing you can probably do is store a custom "Last Modified" field in your BLOB and use that yourself, vs relying on the native `LastModified` provided by Azure BLOB.

Comment: Thanks but I forgot a key piece of info (updated the question): the code doesn't always update LastModified to the current time, so re-uploading doesn't seem like an option unless you can set LastModified upon upload.

Comment: Best thing you can probably do is store a custom "Last Modified" field in your Blob and use that yourself, vs relying on the native `LastModified` provided by Azure BLOB.

Comment: If a blob is changed somehow, `LastModified` property will change automatically by storage service. You don't have to do anything there. For touch operation, I would not recommend doing a re-upload as it may be an expensive operation to perform depending on the size of the blob. I would suggest manipulating blob's metadata or other properties (like cache control, content encoding etc.). See this thread for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371429/touch-a-blob-and-change-its-etag-without-downloading-content-and-uploading-in-wi.

Comment: @GauravMantri makes a great point. I did not think to do that.

Comment: Adding a property inside the blob is not a solution. Content will not allow it probably and it is kinda stupid to track it inside. Agree with Gaurav - Metadata will help.

Answer (score 7):

Azure allows you to add **METADATA** to the containers and blobs.
*LastModified* is an internal property and there is no point to let external parties update it - it should reflect its meaning.

In your case, it seems that you want to keep old values after migrating content, and content might not allow to add property inside. Say, it is an image.

In this case use **Metadata** to add and read additional properties.
[Article about Metadata on MSDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-properties-metadata/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SetMetadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.setmetadata?view=azure-dotnet) method to update `LastModified` property.